# Is there a good or rather better way to finish/smooth FDM prints?

Tags: fdm, smoothing

I'm curious as to whether there's an easier and/or more effective way to smooth/finish my FDM prints. I've read about some online but I'd like a second opinion. I'm mostly using PLA and PLA+.

Comment: Consider to qualify "easier" and "more effective" based on your discoveries, to prevent your question from being closed for being vague and/or opinion based.

Comment: Easier and/or more effective than what? What are we comparing against here? Are you comparing against a process that you currently use, or something that you've read about? If the latter, then what reading have you done online (links to articles, papers, etc.)? Unfortunately, your question is rather nebulous as it stands currently. Also, your question is *possibly* a duplicate of [How do I give 3D-printed parts in PLA a shiny smooth finish?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/11/4762)

Comment: Closed due to lack of feedback from user.